# Order by popularity MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

I want to make a query which, as the title says, orders by popularity.
By popularity i mean, the one with most coments for example:

**ARTICLE TABLE**

```
ID | TITLE
```

**COMMENTS TABLE**

```
ID | COMMENT | ARTICLE_ID
```

The query should `ORDER BY DESC` the `ARTICLE title` depending on the number of comments(`ARTICLE_ID`).

For example:

```
'THIS IS A DUMMY TITLE' <= NUMBER OF COMENTS = 11
'THIS IS THE DUMMY TITLE' <= NUMBER OF COMENTS = 7 
'THIS IS OTHER DUMMY TITLE' <= NUMBER OF COMENTS = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(a.ID) as ARTICLE_ID, max(a.TITLE) as TITLE, sum(1) as COMMENTS
from COMMENTS c
join ARTICLE a on (a.ID = c.ARTICLE_ID)
group by c.ARTICLE_ID
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: It works, would you please explain what the "order by 3 desc" means?

Comment: Oh, right I normally don't use numbers to identify columns in mysql. Thanks a lot guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `commets`.*,`article`.title  
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ARTICLE_ID) AS C, `ARTICLE_ID` FROM `commets` GROUP BY `ARTICLE_ID`) AS TAB JOIN `commets` 
ON TAB.`ARTICLE_ID` = `commets`.`ARTICLE_ID`  JOIN `article` 
ON `article`.`ID` = `commets`.`ARTICLE_ID` 
ORDER BY TAB.C DESC
```

**Explanation**

Ok so here I was assuming that the whole comments rows were needed, so in order not to use aggregate functions with each column obtained in case we wanted to include the GROUP BY in the main select, I have created a table though the inline select to obtain the articles with highest comments :

```
(SELECT COUNT(ARTICLE_ID) AS C, `ARTICLE_ID` FROM `commets` GROUP BY `ARTICLE_ID`)
```

and aliased this table as **TAB**, then joined the article id in this table with the comments tables to obtain the comments columns and the article table to obtain the title of the article, then ordered the whole query by the count column **C** in the inline select.

Comment: Had to make a few changes, already got a correct answer but thanks anyway.